# Finding values in multidimensional arrays of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

The following function retrieves a list of friends of the active user who are majoring in a given subject in college. The data is pulled from the Facebook GRAPH API. (THIS FUNCTION WORKS)...

```
 function getCollegeFriends () {
       $config = array(
       'appId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
       'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
       );
       $facebook = new Facebook($config);
       $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
       try {
       $fql    =   "select uid,name,education from user WHERE uid IN (select uid2 from friend where uid1=($user_id))";
       $param  =   array(
       'method'    => 'fql.query',
       'query'     => $fql,
       'callback'  => ''
       );
       $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
       }
       catch(Exception $o){
       d($o);
       }

       $friends = $fqlResult;
       $friends_BA = array();
       foreach ($friends as $friend) {
       $isBA = false;
           if (is_array($friend['education'])) {
              foreach ($friend['education'] as $school) {
                 if (isset($school)) {
                    foreach ($school['school'] as $name) {
                       $lowerName = strtolower($name);
                       if (strpos($lowerName, 'university of central florida') !== false || strpos($lowerName, 'ucf') !== false) {
                       $friends_BA[] = $friend['name'];
                       continue 3; // skip to the next friend


                       }
                     }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
             echo '<pre>';
             print_r($friends_BA);
             echo '</pre>';
      }
```

Now I'm working on a function to return a list of friends who work for the same company, hold the same job position, etc. Here is my unsuccessful stab at the function:

```
  function getWorkerFriends () {
       $config = array(
       'appId' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
       'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
       );
       $facebook = new Facebook($config);
       $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
       try {
       $fql    =   "select uid,name,work_history from user WHERE uid IN (select uid2 from friend where uid1=($user_id))";
       $param  =   array(
       'method'    => 'fql.query',
       'query'     => $fql,
       'callback'  => ''
       );
       $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
       }
       catch(Exception $o){
       d($o);
       }

       $friends = $fqlResult;
       $friends_BA = array();
       foreach ($friends as $friend) {
       $isBA = false;
           if (is_array($friend['work_history'])) {
              foreach ($friend['work_history'] as $employer) {
                 if (isset($employer)) {
                    foreach ($employer['location'] as $name) {
                       $lowerName = strtolower($name['company_name']);
                       if (strpos($lowerName, 'ubs') !== false || strpos($lowerName, 'merion') !== false) {
                       $friends_BA[] = $friend['name'];
                       continue 3; // skip to the next friend


                       }
                     }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
             echo '<pre>';
             print_r($friends_BA);
             echo '</pre>';
      }
```

This solution just returns an empty array but the test user does have friends who meet the requirements of the function. Below is the array of a user's friends list. Any help with a proposed solution would be greatly appreciated. I'm on day three now of this problem:

(NOTE: Each [OFFSET] is a different friend of the active user:

```
 [124] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 553325624
        [name] => Persons Name
        [current_location] => Array
            (
                [city] => Los Angeles
                [state] => California
                [country] => United States
                [zip] => 
                [id] => 110970792260960
                [name] => Los Angeles, California
            )

        [work_history] => Array
            (
            )

        [education] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 111894272160018
                                [name] => Spanish River Community High School
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 110186095670702
                                [name] => North Broward Preparatory Schools
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

            )

    )

[125] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 560613217
        [name] => Persons Name
        [current_location] => Array
            (
                [city] => Summit
                [state] => New Jersey
                [country] => United States
                [zip] => 
                [id] => 103727996333163
                [name] => Summit, New Jersey
            )

        [work_history] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [location] => Array
                            (
                                [city] => 
                                [state] => 
                            )

                        [company_name] => Camp High Rocks
                        [description] => 
                        [start_date] => 
                        [end_date] => 
                    )

            )

        [education] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 106165586082302
                                [name] => Summit Senior High School
                            )

                        [type] => High School
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [school] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 6192688417
                                [name] => Stanford University
                            )

                        [year] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 105576766163075
                                [name] => 2015
                            )

                        [type] => College
                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: start var_dump 'ing before each foreach() and it should show you where your script fails.

Comment: Where exactly do you mean? And to which variables? I tried a few but just got empty arrays.

Comment: The error will be between the last array that does have data and the first one that does not.

Comment: I know but where exactly do I put var_dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var_dump for every variable until you find an empty one, such as below
Assuming your facebook connect stuff is all working properly try the code below, this should get you some useful output.

```
function getWorkerFriends () {
   $friends = $fqlResult;

   echo "\$friends <br/>";
   var_dump( $friends );

   $friends_BA = array();
   foreach ($friends as $friend) {
   $isBA = false;

        echo "\$friend <br />";
        var_dump( $friend );


       if (is_array($friend['work_history'])) {
          foreach ($friend['work_history'] as $employer) {

              echo "\$employer <br />";
              var_dump( $employer );

             if (isset($employer)) {
                foreach ($employer['location'] as $name) {

                    echo "\$name <br />";
                    var_dump( $name );

                   $lowerName = strtolower($name['company_name']);
                   if (strpos($lowerName, 'ubs') !== false || strpos($lowerName, 'merion') !== false) {
                   $friends_BA[] = $friend['name'];

                   echo "Continue to next friend! <br />";

                   continue 3; // skip to the next friend


                   }
                 }
               }
            }
         }
      }
         echo '<pre>';
         print_r($friends_BA);
         echo '</pre>';
  }
```

Comment: https://join.me/344-811-109 and i'll show you the output. Not sure how to interpret and it's a lot.

Comment: link doesn't work, how about updating your first post with the output?